# Two different Vector3.zero's, but no parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**UPDATE**

I found out that the mesh center of the mesh object is not at 0,0,0. Does that do anything?

I have the following problem. I am generating a terrain from Perlin noise and that works fine. However, as soon as I try to instantiate any objects on it, some are spawned in the terrain area and some completely outside. When I reset the object's transform, it teleports to (0,0,0) as expected, but when I reset another object, that was not instantiated at runtime, the (0,0,0) is at a completely different location! I have no parent set to these objects and no parent set to the other object as well. Below is my code for generating the objects:

```
private void AddRocks(Terrain terrain, int count)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            float randX = Random.Range(0, 256); //256 is my terrain size, the transform is all zeros and 1 for the transform size.
            float randZ = Random.Range(0, 256);
            GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(rockPrefab,
            new Vector3(randX, terrain.terrainData.GetHeight((int)randX, (int)randZ),
            randZ), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

This is my code for generating the perlin noise terrain:

```
TerrainData GenerateTerrain(TerrainData terrainData)
    {
        terrainData.heightmapResolution = width + 1;
        terrainData.size = new Vector3(width, depth, height);
        terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, GenerateHeights());
        return terrainData;
    }

    float[,] GenerateHeights()
    {
        float[,] heights = new float[width, height];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                heights[x, y] = CalculateHeight(x, y);
            }
        }
        return heights;
    }
float CalculateHeight(int x, int y)
    {
        float xCoord = (float)x / width * scale + offsetX;
        float yCoord = (float)y / height * scale + offsetY;

        return Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);
    }
```

This is how I call them in Start:

```
terrain.terrainData = GenerateTerrain(terrain.terrainData);
AddRocks(terrain: terrain, count: 20);
```

This is how it looks after generating:

[image: how it looks]

This is how the rocks look:

[image: rocks]

The rocks are generated from a script that lies on the mainterrain itself.

Comment: btw `TerrainData` is a class, so you don't need to `return terrainData;` to keep the changes. The changes you make to the local `terrainData` are made to the `terrain.terrainData` you pass in. That method can just be `void GenerateTerrain(TerrainData terrainData){/* ... */}` and then you can just do `GenerateTerrain(terrain.terrainData);`.

Comment: Check your prefabs. If the item in the prefab isnt 0,0,0 then it will be offset by that transform location

Comment: @BugFinder the prefab is on 0,0,0 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no parent set to these objects and no parent set to the other object as well.

Actually, you do set parent:

```
GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(rockPrefab,
    new Vector3(randX, terrain.terrainData.GetHeight((int)randX, (int)randZ),
    randZ), Quaternion.identity, rockHolder.transform);
```

The last parameter ( `rockHolder.transform`) is a transform to which the instantiated object will be attached and the position you set will become a `localPosition` of the instantiated object relative to the parent ( `rockHolder`).

But I don't see the `rockHolder` object in the hierarchy view screenshot. Seems like you have `rockHolder.transform = null`, in other words it's not initialized. So, when you call `Instantiate (...)` and pass the `rockHolder.transform` as a desired parent for the rocks, it is `null`, so Unity spawns the objects and assign them to `null` (no parent).

Can't tell if this is the root of the problem but it's certainly not okay anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did not however solve the problem, as the rockholder was at 0,0,0 for testing, so it was no use having it in. I have removed that line of code anyway. Do you have any idea? I even changed the prefab to another one and it still does not work.

Comment: Ah, I see. Another idea: a couple of days ago I had some weird positions of the instantiated objects when I passed the desired position to the `Instantiate(...)` method, so, I decided to set the position afterwards. Like `GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab);` and then `go.position = new Vector3(0, 5f, 10f);` and with this approach it worked fine.

Comment: good idea, sadly that did not work as well. I think I might have found the problem. The mesh of the rock object I am using does not have its centre on 0,0,0. If I however use a simple 3d cube from unity, it all seems to be working fine. Any idea how to change the centre to 0,0,0?

Comment: General approach people use in this case is: create an empty object, make the mesh object the child of the empty one, adjust the local position and rotation of the mesh object so it looks fine, i.e. position at the empty object's center, rotation is correct, and then create a prefab from this construction. A lot of models imported from Blender and such have issues with pivot points and rotation axes, and the above workaround is the easiest way to solve the problem when you can't ask the artist to fix the model.

Comment: After that, when you set the prefab object position and rotation you change the properties of the root empty object while the mesh object attached to it stays at center position of the parent empty object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I manually placed the empty parent with exactly opposite position values, and it worked!